# WebSocket Get using Arduino

Tags: websocket, get, arduino, http-get

I use this code to get a string from server using Web Socket Get on Arduino.

```
void LedState() {

  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
  String leddata;

  if (client.connected()) {
    {
    }
    if (leddata.length() > 0) {
      Serial.print("Received leddata: ");
      Serial.println(leddata);
      if (leddata == "True") {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        Serial.println("led on");
      }
      if (leddata == "False") {
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        Serial.println("led off");
      }
    }
  }
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("disconnected");
    delay(100);
    websocket_connect();       //reconnect with the server 
  }
}
```

The problem is that Arduino get the right value for the first time and remain getting this value for a while (some seconds to some minutes) even if the value is changed, and sometime the value doesn't changed on Arduino.

I used a Web Socket test application to test if the problem is with my server or with Arduino and I run it at the same time with Arduino and it get right values while the Arduino stuck on the last value. And sometime if the connection is lost and after reconnect Arduino gets the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `client.stop();` after `Serial.println("led on");` and after `Serial.println("led off");`.